# Problem with dynamic instanciation with composer

Tags: php, oop

I am learning to compose and libraries. the folder where I find a problem is on:
https://github.com/raoufcode/comp
I installed Composer on my Windows, then I created local classes (src folder) and at the same time I imported a library (erusev / parsedown) via the command line.
the problem is that the library works fine when I instantiate it but my own class located in the Fag.php folder in the source folder does not work when I call with use in index.php.
When I require my class file, it works but I want composer to do the job dynamically
Any solutions for my own class so that it works with Composer please?

Answer (score 0):

I think that when you say "dynamic instantiation" you want to mean class autoloading, So I supose that you should learn how to config the autoloader of composer. That's a link that could be useful.

[How to Autoload Classes With Composer in PHP](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-autoload-classes-with-composer-in-php--cms-35649)

Answer (score -1):

Depending on your git repo, that you linked I can only find following problem:

You try to load the class before the autoloader registerd.

You index.php should look like this:

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php'; // only the autoloader needed to include

use Try\Fag; // use need to be after the auto loader

$fag= new Fag();
```

You already auto load your class with your composer config `autload/psr-4`